# How do the macroscopic observables $T$, $ρ$, and $P$ change in an ideal gas after flowing through a turbine?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, ideal-gas

I’m trying to better understand how turbines effect the flow of gas and gain or expend energy in the process. It’s easy to understand with incompressible fluids as all you need to know is the pressure differential, rate of flow, and density.

Let’s say we have a compressible fluid(ideal gas to be more specific) flowing through a pipe of cross-sectional area A with flow rate f(kg/s), temperature T, density ρ, pressure P, velocity v(v=f/Aρ), heat capacity ratio γ. The gas flows through a turbine of efficiency η and the turbine produces W watts of energy as a result. What are T, ρ, and P for the gas after it passes through the turbine?

Comment: Are you asking how to analyze this in terms of the 1st and 2nd laws of thermodynamics?

Comment: @ChetMiller I suppose. I want to know the equations that govern this interaction and I haven't properly understood the sources I've come across.

Comment: What part from the sources don't you understand?

Comment: @ChetMiller How to use them to get those final values for the gas after it passes through the turbine. It's a deterministic system where we know all the inputs, right? We should be able to calculate the outputs from that. Is the effect of having a turbine making W watts of energy similar to the gas flowing through a gravitational potential differential of ΔP=W/f? No thermal energy flows through the pipe walls if that helps.

Comment: This is worked out in every thermo book.  See Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics.